# Flutter widget to display dynamic array of pixel data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

Is there any straightforward way in Flutter that I could display an image each frame whose pixel data is directly controlled by logic in the program? As an analogy, in Java, we have the `BufferedImage` whose pixel data can be directly manipulated by the programmer and can be updated in the display each frame. Or in SDL, we can make a surface whose pixel data is a read/write-able region of memory to achieve a similar effect. Is there anything remotely similar in Flutter? The next-best thing I can find so far in Flutter is constructing a BMP image as a `Uint8List` and passing it to `Image.memory`, but this function seems to take a considerable amount of time (10-20 ms?) to construct even a very small viewable image from the raw data before it appears on-screen. Before this it is simply blank, which would cause flickering in any real application. I am also concerned with how slow it is even for small images, which may render techniques like double-buffering, which may resolve flickering, still unhelpful for larger images. Is there anything like a way to modify the underlying image data of an `Image` object, so I can change the raw pixel data without needing to construct a whole new `Image`?

Answer (score 0):

(note - I would have put this in as a comment but I don't have enough reputation points, sorry about that)

you can also use The dart:ui function decodeImageFromPixels which takes Uint8List as input but for a full screen this is also slow (on iPad 1366 by 1024, generation 4 iPad) it takes around 25mSec.
I was hoping to use isolates and then break up the screen into say 4 to increase this time to something usable. decodeImageFromPixels doesn't allow me to do this for an unknown reason, so I have been looking at creating a BMP (as you suggest), but from your comment about Image.memory being slow this also might not be an option.